# A room owner can put chat in timeout while being suspended

Tags: bug, chat, account-suspension, chat-timeout

I got suspended on [chat.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com), while being an room owner for the [Sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox).

I tried to put the room in timeout from the [image: room] menu and it [succeeded](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64214793#64214793):

[image: This room was placed in timeout for 1 minute; Can I really do that? (Timestamp 14:37)]

Should this feature be disabled for suspended users (suspended room owners)?

Comment: If any user wishes to contest their own suspension, they may do so directly but we don't act based on demands from other users. I will state that this question has nothing to do with the suspension. Beyond that, I need y'all to respect that suspensions are private to protect the recipient unless they wish to discuss it or give express permission for mods to do so.