# Why were the Room owners of the Sandbox purged?

Tags: discussion, chat

In the [Sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1), all of the room owners were [removed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/conversation/the-mass-ro-purge-and-a-new-addition) and a new one was added. Why?

Comment: It could be related to this as it deals with the same room: [A room owner can put chat in timeout while being suspended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392362/a-room-owner-can-put-chat-in-timeout-while-being-suspended)

Comment: Looks like one flood too much, and abusing RO powers, all the owners except the suspended one most likely never asked to be owners, or did so in the past and it's no longer relevant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Joe W](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/203827/joe-w) [was right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1312383) that [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392362/369802) brought it to moderators' attention that there were quite a few Room Owners for the Sandbox. And since the room really doesn't need that, these users shouldn't have been manually or automatically appointed.

Since use of some room owner powers like kicking users can have unintended consequences (like leaving traces on chat user profiles that may confuddle future moderation, automatic moderator only chat flags or even block a user from creating new rooms) a decision was made to clean up the list of Room Owners for the Sandbox, so no innocent users can get marked by a Room Owner testing their powers in what is, after all, a sandbox.

To avoid the system automatically appointing a random Room Owner (as it does that if there are none), one user was used as a default.

Comment: Confirming that this accurately represents the reasons for why this happened.

Comment: Hmm, but https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1?m=64218878#64218878

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard yes, we're keeping an eye on that, apparently appointing one RO didn't entirely prevent the process picking an extra, but that should be solved now too. If it's not, feel free to let us know and we'll de-RO whatever user the process picked and continue figuring out a way to prevent it happening again.

Comment: That happened because the automatic system that appoints ROs checks not only if there are no ROs, but also that at least one RO is regularly in the room, and if none of them are, it appoints one. One way to fix the problem for a given room is to make a bot that posts one message every 24 hours and appoint it as an RO.